# Direction on setting up fiddler and Bluestacks

Tags: android, fiddler, sniffing, bluestacks

Does anyone know how to set up `fiddler` to monitor/sniff traffic from `bluestacks`? I've seen others mentioning that it can be done, but need some direction on configuring `fiddler` or configuring `bluestacks` to get it going. Currently `fiddler` is returning a message, some tunnel to message. Perhaps I would need to configure the `port`/`proxy` for `bluestacks`. If this is the case, does anyone know how this is to be done or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You can capture Bluestacks traffic using:

- Wireshark (problem: we can't see https (SSL) traffic)..
- We can use ProxyCap software and setup all BlueStacks executables to work via our Fiddler local proxy. But we have an issue here - We can't import Fiddler Certificate into BlueStacks (at least I didn't found a way yet)..

one possible solution would be to:

- KILL BlueStacks processes.
- Find BlueStacks Root.fs file (in my case it's located here: c:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\Android)
- edit that file using linux tools (it's an image .. we can do fdisk Root.fs to see partitions.. then mout it with loop rw .. and modify.. but that's need more digging).

one important note: we need to find a way to block BlueStacks autoupdates (and discard our changes in Root.fs)

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, BlueStacks doesn't support proxy settings (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27224/how-to-configure-bluestack-appplayer-to-use-proxy-settings-when-connecting-to-ne) which would imply that its traffic would not go through Fiddler.

However, you say "Fiddler is returning a message some tunnel to message" which implies to me that maybe they were incorrect and the traffic *is* going through Fiddler and the client merely needs to be configured to trust the Fiddler root certificate.

Can you share a screenshot of the Fiddler UI showing the "Tunnel to" in question?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this 'change file permission in BlueStacks player qwerty.kl' http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53448/change-file-permission-in-bluestacks-player-qwerty-kl

Comment: We have a way to proivide proxy settings in bluestacks.

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is to set a *browser* within Bluestacks proxy, this proxy setting app worked for me:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lechucksoftware.proxy.proxysettings